# Redundancy in Levenshtein distance algorithm

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

In the typical dynamic Levenshtein distance algorithm, to compute the value of cell `d[i][j]`, where `i` and `j` are the row and column numbers, respectively, we take the minimum of `d[i-1][j-1]+0/1`, `d[i-1][j]+1` and `d[i][j-1]+1`. However, it seems to me that the minimum of `d[i-1][j-1]+0/1` and `d[i-1][j]+1` is always going to be `d[i-1][j-1]+0/1`, in which case including `d[i-1][j]+1` in the computation seems redundant. Is it ever the case that `d[i-1][j-1]+0/1` > `d[i-1][j]+1` in the Levenshtein distance algorithm, and if not, wouldn't it be more efficient to omit this comparison?

EDIT: Sorry for the under-researched question; any standard run of the algorithm shows instances where `d[i-1][j-1]+0/1` > `d[i-1][j]+1`:

```
    A
 +-+-+
 |0|1|
 +-+-+
A|1|0|
 +-+-+
```

(consider the second row).

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), the minimum in the last case must be taken in the "deletion" case.

Suppose we want to calculate the Levenshtein distance between `abc` and `ab` (from now on fixed and omitted from notation).

Iterative evaluation yields the following intermediate results.

```
lev(0,0) = 0 (1st case applies)
lev(0,1) = 1 (1st case applies)
lev(0,2) = 2 (1st case applies)

lev(1,0) = 1 (1st case applies)
lev(1,1) = min(2,2,0) (2nd case, minimum taken in last term) = 0
lev(1,2) = min(1,2,1) (2nd case, minumum taken in last term) = 1

lev(2,0) = 2 (1st case applies)
lev(2,1) = min(3,1,2) (2nd case, minimum taken in second term) = 1 (*)
lev(2,2) = min(2,2,0) (2nd case, minimum taken in the last term) = 0

lev(3,0) = 3 (1st case applies)
lev(3,1) = min(4,2,2) (2nd case, minimum taken in the second and third term) = 2
lev(3,2) = min(3,1,2) (2nd case, minimum taken in the second term) = 1 (*)
```

The row marked with (*) are cases where the second case occurs, but the minimum is *not* taken in the last term. An online calculator also showing the dynamic programming table can be found [here](http://odur.let.rug.nl/kleiweg/lev/).

Comment: Yes it does, if `a[i] == b[j]`.

Comment: "Note that this implementation does not fit the definition precisely" - though this version is deemed equivalent, I'm looking for a solution in terms of the traditional variant.

Comment: @SeanKelleher Okay thanks for your remark; do you refer to a specific presentation of the algorithm? If yes, please include it in your question, it will make communication a bit easier. In fact, I realize I somewhat misread the notation for the last case there.

Comment: @SeanKelleher Regarding the reasoning behind the algorithm, the minimum must be attained in the "mismatch" case.

Comment: @Codor I've edited the question as I've realised the answer is trivial. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SeanKelleher Well you're welcome, it was a quite insightful hour.